# Drupal Domain Views display user's assigned domains

Tags: drupal, dns, drupal-7, view

I'm creating an overview page at admin/people where i want to filter and show the listed domains of an user. I've already implemented the views_vbo module for filtering but i can't quite display all the assigned domains of an user.

I only get the first result of the assigned domains when i use the field:

"Domain Editor: Domain ID" which clearly states in the description: "The domain(s) an editor is assigned to.", is there any way to display all the users' domains?